# Bubble Sort from an SQL Select statement

Tags: python, sql, bubble-sort

Select Statements shown are put into a list after being fetched and should be sorted to display the biggest to the smallest number. No error is displayed, however, the numbers from the sort are not sorted when displayed? Please help :)

It is outputting ["('72,000,000',)('221,882,777',)('35,569,993',)"] when first collected and also when supposed to be sorted.

```
tablesconnect.execute("SELECT Current_Views FROM Stray_Kids WHERE Order_of_CB = 1")
SKZCurrentViews = tablesconnect.fetchone()
print (SKZCurrentViews)
SKZCurrentViews = str(SKZCurrentViews)

tablesconnect.execute("SELECT Current_Views FROM TWICE WHERE Order_of_CB = 1")
TWICECurrentViews = tablesconnect.fetchone()
print (TWICECurrentViews)
TWICECurrentViews = str(TWICECurrentViews)

tablesconnect.execute("SELECT Current_Views FROM NCT_127 WHERE Order_of_CB = 1")
NCT127CurrentViews = tablesconnect.fetchone()
print (NCT127CurrentViews)
NCT127CurrentViews = str(NCT127CurrentViews)

Compare = [(SKZCurrentViews)+(TWICECurrentViews)+(NCT127CurrentViews)]
print (Compare)
```

n = len(Compare)

```
for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range (0, n-i-1):
        if Compare[j] > Compare[j+1]:
            Compare[j], Compare[j+1] = Compare[j+1], Compare[j]
print(Compare)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write your bubble sort algorithm this way to get the correct output :

```
for i in range(n): # Here was the error, you should iterate with range(n) not range(n - 1)

    for j in range (0, n - i - 1):

        if Compare[j] > Compare[j+1]:

            Compare[j], Compare[j+1] = Compare[j+1], Compare[j]

print(Compare)
```

Comment: Just tried this, it did not change the outcome, it still prints "["('72,000,000',)('221,882,777',)('35,569,993',)"]" which as you can tell, is not in any sort of order

Comment: I guess, you should first convert the `compare` elements into `int` first by `int()`.